# CMake cpprestsdk

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, cpprest-sdk

I'm on a windows 10 machine. I have installed cpprestsdk using vcpkg

```
vcpkg install cpprestsdk
```

My CMakeLists.txt has the following lines

```
find_package(cpprestsdk CONFIG REQUIRED) 
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cpprestsdk::cpprest cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_zlib_internal cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_boost_internal cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_brotli_internal)
```

running

```
cmake -GNinja .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="C:\Program Files\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake"
```

gives me the following error

```
Make Error at C:/Program Files/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:250 (_add_library):
Target "<target_name_hidden>" links to targe
"cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_boost_internal" but the target was not found.
Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an
```

ALIAS target is missing?

Comment: Normally "internal" prefix/suffix in a name means this name is **internal to implementation** and shouldn't be used outside. Why do you use `cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_zlib_internal` instead of simple [find_package(ZLIB)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindZLIB.html)?

Answer (score 0):

[find zlib](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/Release/cmake/cpprest_find_zlib.cmake) - find module introduces interface library `cpprestsdk_zlib_internal` which doesn't have install instructions so will not be available in namespace `cpprestsdk` and wasn't imported

Comment: If I remove cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_boost_internal but keep the cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_zlib_internal it works fine. What is it exactly that you're asking me  to do here? @vsh

Comment: infact installing via vcpkg suggests this

 find_package(cpprestsdk CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE cpprestsdk::cpprest cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_zlib_internal cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_boost_internal cpprestsdk::cpprestsdk_openssl_internal)